# Data gets truncated while inserting JSON data

Tags: sql-server, json, coldfusion

I have a SQL table which has 'text' as a datatype. I am trying to insert JSON data using CfQueryparam with cf_sql_longvarchar, which I have in a ColdFusion variable.

However, when I checked the value in my column, I'm losing the data. I compared the total length of my column inSQL table to data being held. I've enough datalength left in that column.

Comment: How many bytes are we talking here?

Comment: Column data length is 2147483647 and data getting inserted in around 90K.

Comment: 1) Did you enable the "CLOB" setting in your datasource? Otherwise it truncates at around 64K 2) What versions of MS SQL and CF? 3) Exactly how are you verifying the lengths? Post a small self-contained repro case.

Comment: I ran queries to DATALENGTH - to get data stored in column and another one to check the total length of column itself.

[code]select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length    
  from information_schema.columns  
 where table_name = 'myTable'
 AND column_name = 'myColumn'

Comment: @Aniruddha - What about the other questions? Also, you should also test the length of the raw data before the insert, to verify you are actually inserting what you think you are.

Comment: @MattBusche - There is probably something undocumented, if you do not have admin access. But I am not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: Total length of JSON is close to 89K and inserted data is 87K. I did text compare on both of them and can see the difference in data i.e one that's not being inserted is the end part of JSON data.

Comment: @Aniruddha Will you please try something like following.
Create a simple string having same length as JSON string you are inserting without any special char or commas like["'!@#$]. Then try to insert that and check if you are getting original data back.
It will help us to check if the problem is with data or something else.

Comment: Same code works when JSON has less data. So for some accounts which has more fields I'm getting this issue.

Comment: Is your column defined in BYTE or CHAR? It may be the problem with certain characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has to do with the settings in your datasource under the CF admin.

I would mess with the CLOB and your char buffer values and see what you can come up with.

[image]

Comment: That was the issue. I got it fixed based on earlier comments. Thanks for the image and answer.

Comment: *I got it fixed based on earlier comments* Lol, then next time you might want to *respond* to the questions in the comments. So people do not waste time making other suggestions when the problem is already resolved ;-) Despite being asked twice about that setting, you never answered ...

Comment: This is happening to me even with the above settings.